# how to loop on vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

im new to vue js

usually passing the variable to blade with @foreach

i have a joined table like this

[image]

so, there could be multiple ref_contract_id

i've tried with v-for, but only 4 blank rows appeared

[image]

here's my vue

```
<tr v-for="material in getmaterial">
<td></td>
<td>{{ material.product_name }}</td>
<td>{{ material.qty }}</td>
<td>{{ material.price }}</td>
<td>{{ material.budget }}</td>
```

```
export default {
  props: ['getmaterial'],
  data() {
    return {
      module_url: `${this.$root.base_url}/supplier-comparison`,
      forms: {
        action: {          
          quotation_no: '',
          project_code: '',
          rof_code: '',
          submit: 'Create',
        }
      },
    }
  },
```

Comment: The `v-for` directive is the proper way to iterate. What have you done to verify the value of the `getmaterial` prop?

Comment: @hmm i put getmaterial in prop because thats when im trying to check if the variable is passed without  loop

Comment: Do you have 4 records on this table?

Comment: @livresonltc no, only 1 record based by the where clause

Comment: How many records you have on this table? Also share you database query and how you are fetching data from vue js.

Comment: don't forget to provide a unique key attribute for each item in the v-for directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure 'getmaterial' has any data by consol.log(this.getmaterial) it on mount (or in a method) in the script section or adding it in the template as {{getmaterial}}.
2. With v-for, always use a key
   `<tr v-for="(material, index) in getmaterial" :key="index">`

V-for needs a unique key Id while iterating and index will provide the current index as an id

Hope this helps!